# Renaming a column in a dataframe without getting an Attribute Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Anytime I have renamed this Unnamed Column, I either get an Attribute: NoneType Error or the column itself does not change. This is an excel file not a csv file.

I have been trying to rename this 'Unnamed: 0' in multiple ways in pandas. However I've only either gotten an Attribute None Type Error, or it does not change the data frame column at all. I've done the rename multiple ways and it still did not work. I was able to change the NaT column but not the Unnamed column and I'm unsure as to why this is not occurring. I've tried it as

```
properties=properties.rename( columns={0:'new column name'}, inplace= True )
properties=properties.rename( columns={"Unnamed: 0":"new column name"}, inplace= True )
properties = properties.rename( columns={"0": "new column name"}, inplace = True)
properties=properties.rename(columns={0:'new column name'})
```

If anyone is able to help me and see what I did wrong it would help greatly. I have had it without the inplace = True as well. It does not change the column name still.
[image]
[image]

Comment: remove `inplace=True`. example : df.drop('A') 1. you can make result to df `df = df.drop('A')` [O] 2. you can use inplace True. `df.drop('A', inplace=True)` [O]. 3. you caaaaaan't use both. `df= df.drop('A', inplace=True)` [X]

Comment: As told by @PandaKim remove `inplace=True` as that will modify the dataframe instead of providing a new one and will simply return None, hence you get that error. 
Refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#:~:text=Returns,inplace%3DTrue.